# How to throw error or exit from Azure ARM template when error in custom extension script

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I have ARM template which will do the following

1. Create a Cluster
2. Create a VM
3. Install package (sample.sh) on VM using Linux Custom Extensions

Parallel Execution:-

- Above [1] and [2] are started in parallel
- After [2] finished, [3] will start

I want to make VM custom Extension get failed suddenly if any package installation failure in sample.sh irrespective of cluster is running in the template

How can I achieve it?

Comment: in this case you need to redo your question. it has nothing to do with azure\arm-templates

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have updated my question.

Comment: It seems you need to find how to exit the script with non-zero exit status when the failure occurs. Really nothing to do with ARM templates.